# Drag&drop ghost image cannot be wider than 290 px

Tags: javascript, css, html, drag-and-drop

The code below works and allows dragging but the "ghost" image looks just transparent when the width of the #blue is about 280px or 290px or less:
[image]

When it's something like 400px or 700px instead of becoming a bit transparent it gets some gradient opacity, like this:

[image]

```js
var source;

var fake = document.getElementById('fake');

function isbefore(a, b) {
    if (a.parentNode == b.parentNode) {
        for (var cur = a; cur; cur = cur.previousSibling) {
            if (cur === b) { 
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
} 

function dragenter(e) {


    if (isbefore(fake, e.target)) {
        e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(fake, e.target);
    }
    else {
        e.target.parentNode.insertBefore(fake, e.target.nextSibling);
    }
}

function dragstart(e) {

    var crt = document.getElementById('ghost');
     
    source = e.target;
 
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'anything');  

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';

    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(crt , 0, 0);
}
```

```css
[draggable] 
{
    user-select: none;
}
body 
{
    background-color: #fff; 
    color: #303; 
    font-family: sans-serif; 
    text-align: center;
}
li 
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 800px;    
}
ul 
{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 25%;
}
#fake
{
    border: 2px dotted black;
    background-color: white;
}
#ghost
{
    background-color:blue;
    width: 380px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)">Apples</li>
    <li draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)">Oranges</li>
    <li draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)">Bananas</li>
    <li draggable="true" ondragenter="dragenter(event)" ondragstart="dragstart(event)">Strawberries</li>
    <li id="fake">&nbsp;</li>
    <li id="ghost">GHOST</li>       
</ul>
```

How can I make the "ghost" element be either non-transparent or have normal, not gradient transparency?

Comment: Does this happen only in specific browsers/OS/versions?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I happens on both Firefox and Chrome under Windows7 64bit. I don't think it's system specific but cannot test. Does it work fine for you?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on Chrome/OSX.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on Chrome/OSX.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Did you try moving the red elements around?

Comment: Yes, I dragged them around, and resized the elements to see if I could replicate.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Thanks!